# How does spontaneous symmetry breaking (SSB) happen?

Tags: standard-model, phase-transition, higgs, symmetry-breaking, thermal-field-theory

I've just finished studying for an exam on the Standard Model (so electroweak theory and symmetry breaking) and I can't figure out how this question never crossed my mind. I'm now studying the QCD chiral symmetry breaking, but I think my question applies to any (physical) SSB.

I know what SSB is (symmetry of the Lagrangian but not of the states) and I also know how one implements it in a theory (scalar sector with a mexican-hat potential) and it's clear to me the implications of the two different phases, the broken one and the restored one (vev for the nonbroken scalars, Goldstone bosons eventually "eaten" by the gauge bosons).
What I don't understand is, **how does the phase transition work?** How did the universe go from one phase to the other?
Does the potential just "switch on"? Is it always on but at high energies the quantum/thermal fluctuations don't "see" its structure?

Comment: Suppose the only SSB you knew about, rather than Higgs, was an upright pen falling in a random direction when you take your finger off it. This has a $U(1)$ symmetry, like the Higgs found in scalar electrodynamics. We can't predict or explain that direction, but it's obvious that the SSB is due to reducing potential, like so much dynamics.

Comment: @J.G. I understand what you're saying but I don't think it answers the question. In you example gravity on the pen and friction on the tip are what "causes" the SSB. What is that causes the electroweak or chiral SSBs? Also, someone had to put the pen in an upright position for the pen to be that way. Why should the universe start in a non-stable configuration?

Comment: You are familiar with the variation of the effective Higgs potential with temperature, no? Are you asking about general phase transitions, even outside QFT, or thermal QFT, instead?

Comment: @CosmasZachos no, I'm not familiar with pretty much anything that mixes QFT and temperature. Should I look it up? Also, I'd like to understand better the QFT phase transitions in particular, but a broader answer would still be appreciated.

Comment: As for the Higgs, at high temperatures the symmetric minimum is actually the true minimum . When the temperature becomes small enough a new, broken, minimum appears. Roughly speaking, the Higgs field can "travel" to this other minimum via thermal escape, and a phase transition can occur.

Comment: [Yes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/555513/is-the-analytical-dependence-of-the-theoretical-higgs-potential-with-temperature), there is an entire field of thermal QFT...

Comment: [This](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.9.3357) is a mother paper, but perhaps too rich for an intro... Try [this](https://scipost.org/SciPostPhysLectNotes.24/pdf).

Comment: I posted a comment precisely because I didn't think it constituted a full answer; its purpose, like any good comment, is to begin a clarification of what one would have to do. Here are just two ways my comment achieved its objective, if only by a process of elimination: (i) The role of gravity is just that of the potential you already understand, so that's not the hard part. (ii) The pen will end up flat no matter how it starts, so that's not the hard part either.

Comment: @Lunaron That looks like the beginning of an answer, not a comment - please consider writing an answer.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Likewise - please consider writing an *answer*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just sketching the trail map of where your question might wish to go... it is a subject of limitless complexity.

The universe cools down, and [thermal QFT](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0005272) dictates [mutation of the Higgs potential with temperature](https://doi.org/10.21468/SciPostPhysLectNotes.24), section 3.

This mutation of the effective Higgs potential from the form favoring the symmetric phase to one favoring SSB at lower temperature describes when the phase transition is likely to switch on, at $T_c$.

[image]

Comment: I'm baffled by the fact that you often seek "where the question might wish to go". Your answer is a perfectly good answer for a question that doesn't really want to go anywhere: I didn't know that the temperature changed the form of the potential, now I do. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think for phase transition one necessarily needs a thermal phase transition. Quantum phase transitions suffice.

Comment: In the early universe, which is what the OP suggests, the transition *was* thermal. This may be not quite an academic question….

Comment: I don't see how? What do you mean by OP?

Comment: Original posting. It is the accepted theory of the evolution of the universe. Mainstream physics need not be argued for ab initio.

Comment: Let me know why Quantum Phase transition doesn't reproduce the same results without resorting to thermal phase transition.

Comment: I am not a cosmologist, but the accepted mainstream scenario certainly monitors thermal evolution, from the Wigner to the Nambu mode realization. Coleman - Weinberg has lost out for decades, and its demise merits a separate question.

Comment: The phenomenology of the mainstream [thermal picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroweak_epoch) works out pretty well.

Comment: Coleman-Weinberg is dead? Since when? It can solve the naturalness problem with at least two viable scenarios that are way modest in comparison to alternatives like SUSY that everybody sticks to! It's mind-blowing the way you present "physics". You're not a cosmologist and you exclude an argument based on an already good and yet not better alternative? I mean I'm quite into any statement against the CW mechanism if there are any computations that logically negate it regarding cosmology. If there are no such investigations I see no point in its exclusion. Please illuminate us with some logic.

Comment: Sigh... My point is that C-W is dead as a doornail in describing the early universe. It's a  neat mechanism to discuss in all kinds of GUT model-building, but has been excluded from early universe considerations for decades. As I insist, If you believe CW, a modification of the potential, once and for all, due to radiative corrections, can provide insights into the cooldown of the expanding universe, you should ask a separate question as to why mainstream cosmologists don't rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

Well in any QFT, the origin of SSB can be traced back to the loop Quantum corrections as was pointed out beautifully by Sidney Coleman and Eric Weinberg for the first time.

The analogy with solid state physics is helpful but not precisely and (necessarily) what takes place in QFT.

There are several variants of SSB, Global, Local, Chiral, Dynamical etc. But in all these cases SSB is due to quantum fluctuations.(At least at the level of Peskin Schroeder which is all written at zero temperature)

The effective action formalism(used for the first time by Jona Lasinio in the context of QFT) can shed enormous light on the physics of SSB in QFT as makes the solid state analogy even closer to real while one should keep in mind, SSB in QFT happens at zero temperature(though one can extend it to finite temperature QFT in a more advanced level) so the anology with solid state shouldn't be taken literally, and the role of temperature in QFT is basically played by a controlling parameter like vacuum expectation value of a Quantum Field(say scalar).

The following paper might help:

- S. Coleman and E. Weinberg, *Radiative Corrections as the Origin of Spontaneous Symmetry Breaking*, [Phys. Rev. D **7**, 1888 (1973)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.7.1888).

EDIT:

In fact "why the initial state is at the tip of the Mexican hat" can be answered this way in my opinion:

I'd say perhaps the question can be answered from a more diplomatic point of view. One can assume the initial temperature is so high that quantum fluctuations are dominated by thermal fluctuations and one has a prabolic potential, and this preseves the vacuum at the bottom of the well, and as the temperature decreases then at a certain point the quantum fluctuations can dominate the statistical ones, where the old vacuum tunnels into the new one.[In fact it can be even more complicated, the potential might not be necessarily parabolic but that "suffices" to make my point]

The first regime is where $kT>ℏω$ and the second one is where $kT<ℏω$. And all this is to avoid nonsensical negative mass terms needed for thermal phase transition! That's the root cause of my objection to thermal phase transition as the ultimate proposal for SSB in particle physics!

Comment: This seems like a good answer but I don't think I understand it. What does it mean, precisely, "due to quantum fluctuations"? In what sense the temperature is a "controlling parameter"? To be clear, I'm asking how the SSB whose theory one studies when studying QFTs *actually* happen, what is *breaking* the symmetry and making the phase transition happen.

Comment: Suppose you've got a ball at the minimum of a potential that fulfills the original symmetry of the theory. This is quite classical. What happens is that if you add loop corrections to the classical potential(a perturbative series in Planck constant), then the shape of the potential changes to that of a mexican hat! Then, the ball that is steady at the local maximum of the new potential undergoes Quantum Tunneling and moves to the absolute minimum of the Quantum potential! This is how Quantum theory leads to phase transition. It's called Quantum phase transition at zero temperature.

Comment: In solid state physics the controlling parameter is the temperature. But in QFT the controlling parameter(order parameter) is the vacuum expectation value of the field that can be even space-time dependent in general and even break the translational invariance.

Comment: that's a lot more clear, the fact that quantum loop corrections reshape the potential. One last thing though: a quantum correction doesn't *happen*, it isn't an event, it's a correction of something that already there. But the SSB *happens*, meaning that the early universe underwent a reshaping of the scalar potential. What *happened* there? The currently accepted answer seems to say that "a drop in temperature happened" and I found that satisfying. What's the "quantum fluctuations" version of this?

Comment: The false vacuum decay comprises the Quantum Phase transition. Is purely a Quantum Mechanical incident that can be investigated thanks to time dependent instanton solutions. The reality is that the original vacuum state(even though the potential was of Mexican hat type) was due to the ball residing at the local maximum. But tunneling effect will cause the change of the vacuum state from the original one to a more stable one.

Comment: Choose several points in the early spacetime, and then the points expand spherically. Within each sphere the direction of symmetry breaking is different and the expansion of the sphere radius guarantees the ongoing process of SSB in all directions. If such spheres collide they form interesting cosmological objects, generally called topological defects such as, monopoles, cosmic strings etc. So basically it's an ongoing process of cosmic scale tunneling from an unstable vacuum to a more stable one. That's the thing which is happening and happened.

Comment: but *why* was the ball at the local maximum? Why is there a "breaking" and not just a broken case to start with?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/519613/higgs-mechanism-and-phase-transition

Comment: @MauroGiliberti I thought more about your question. In fact "why the initial state in at the tip of the mexican hat". I'd say perhaps the question can be answered from a more diplomatic point of view. One can assume the initial temperature is so high that quantum fluctuations are dominated by thermal fluctuations and one has a prabolic potential, and this preseves the vacuum at the bottom of the well, and as the temperature decreases then at a certain point the quantum fluctuations can dominate the statistical ones, where the old vacuum tunnels into the new one.

Comment: The first regime is where $kT> \hbar \omega$ and the second one is where $kT< \hbar \omega$. And all this is to avoid nonsensical negative mass terms needed for thermal phase transition! That's the root cause of my objection to thermal phase transition as the ultimate proposal for SSB in particle physics!