# Is the early universe cosmology phase transition thermal or quantum? WHY?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, phase-transition, symmetry-breaking

In this question [How does SSB happen?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/684630/181792), one of the answers assumes the nature of the early universe phase transition to be ***thermal***. I need to know why can't such phase transition be a ***quantum*** phase transition just like the Coleman-Weinberg mechanism where quantum loop corrections to the classical action change the potential shape?

Answer (score 0):

In general every phase-transition is quantum in a sense that you have your effective action and your theory with its finite (hopefully) number of couplings. Depending on the environment / energy scale your couplings can be stronger/ weaker. The shape of the potential doesn't change, there will be no new elements. The theory is fixed but it depends on the energy scale or if you like, temperature. Thus certain effects which are dominating at high energies may become negligible for lower temperature, thus technically you could change your equations (seemingly), however it is still the same theory.

In such a dynamical system where the spacetime is undergoing an expansion + the temperature is rapidly decreasing + other early universe phenomena happens, its hard to talk about true equilibrium. But the thermodynamics of the early universe is a complex phenomena.

Of course subsystems were in equilibrium, as an example: e- + e+ = 2 gamma, pair creation and inverse were happening at the same rate until the temperature / pressure decreased enough that the probability of the inverse became small, so techinally photons started freely roaming without collision,and the "freez out" happened. There were several such freez outs, for example for the neutrino too. This is also a phase transition, and here a chemical potential could effectively describe physics.

My last comment is, that perturbation theory is not the top, not everything has to be described by perturbative expansion.